# return a object and image from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a controller which make a image in fly and **return that to a view** with a text in ViewBag,

```
public partial class TextController : Controller
{

    public virtual ActionResult Index(bool noisy = true)
    {

    //image stream
    FileContentResult img;

    using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(130, 30))
    using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp))
    {
        gfx.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

        //add question
        gfx.DrawString(text, new Font("Tahoma", 15), Brushes.Gray, 2, 3);

        //render as Jpeg
        bmp.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        img = File(mem.GetBuffer(), "image/Jpeg");
    }
    ViewBag.text = text;
    return img;
}
```

}
i want return a image and ViewBag from controller.
what is solution?how ican do this work?

Comment: What? Can you rephrase it please?

Comment: Is this controller Index action expected to return html with img in it?

Comment: yes,i want return a html or any string data with a image from controller.

Answer (score 2):

Your ViewBag will be totally useless if your Action returns an Image. When an Action returns an Image (through a [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), not the way you did), it is sent to the browser, you cannot use the ViewBag later to do anything with it.

If you want to present image and text, the best way is to return a standard CSHTML view, in which you can show the image and the text. You can save the image while in the Action (which is strange but acceptable) and pass the URL to the view which can put it inside an `img` html tag. A much nicer approach would be to create a separate Action to generate the image itself returning a FileResult

Comment: please show with a example how i can "save the image while in the Action".

Comment: my viewbag relevant to image and must generate together in same controller.

Comment: i can call another action method in this controller and pass text to that action method and return a view?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an action that returns a partial view. You can either save the dynamically generated image in some physical location and refer that to the image src. If you don't want to save the image you could convert the image to a base-64 encoded string and set it to the src attribute.